# Random date calculation bootstrap datapicker, on adding days to specific date

Tags: javascript, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I spend whole day to the issue and tried uncountable ways to solve this. Ok So I was trying a get new date by adding num. of days to specified day on after adding num. of days.

New date = start date + num. of days

```
   $('.duration').change(function(){
        var days = $(this).val();           
       var booking_from=  $( "#datetimepicker1" ).datepicker( "getDate" );
         var endDate = new Date();
        endDate.setDate(booking_from.getDate()+days); 
        $('#datetimepicker2').datepicker('setDate', endDate);
    });
```

But here in datetimepicker2 any random date is coming. I am not getting how these dates is calculating by datepicker and what wrong parameter I am passing? Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call parseInt on the value from the jquery val() and do the initializing of the endDate a little differently:

```
$('.duration').change(function() {
  var days = parseInt($(this).val());
  var bookingFrom = $('#datetimepicker1').datepicker('getDate');
  var endDate = new Date(bookingFrom);
  endDate.setDate(bookingFrom.getDate() + days);
  $('#datetimepicker2').datepicker('setDate', endDate);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate implies this should work:

```
$('#datetimepicker2').datepicker('setDate', booking_from.getDate()).datepicker('setDate','+'+days);
```

After comment "doesn't work":
Uh, yeah .. the "+/-days" approach is relative to TODAY anyway ;-P
This is what works for me:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: "@"});
var day_2014dec01 = new Date(2014,11,1,12,34,56); 
$('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', ""+day_2014dec01.getTime() );
```

The "dateFormat @" is for unix time - see http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate .. keeps the example simple. You can switch to that for the calculation and then back again to whatever format you like for human or database readability, if required.

Comment: Not working. :( Booking_from date is only getting in datetimepicker2

Answer (score 0):

you can make some millisecond operations

```
function getNewDate(start,num_of_days){
  var newTime = num_of_days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 + start.getTime();
  undefined
  var newDate = new Date(newTime);
  return newDate;
}


endDate.setDate(getNewDate(booking_from,days));
```

or

```
$('.duration').change(function(){
    var days = $(this).val();           
   var booking_from=  $( "#datetimepicker1" ).datepicker( "getDate" );
    var endDate = new Date(Date.now() + days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    $('#datetimepicker2').datepicker('setDate', endDate);
});
```